# Install python package from Azure Artifacts feed in GitHub Actions

Tags: azure-devops, pip, github-actions, pypi, azure-artifacts

I am trying to build a project on GitHub Action workflow where some of my python package requirements are hosted in Azure Artifacts.

I've managed to install these dependencies locally using pip but this requires fetching personal access token from Azure DevOps and entering it interactively to CLI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/python-cli?view=azure-devops

What would be the best way to authenticate to Azure artifacts in GitHub Actions to be able to install the required packages?